# Remove all people from pictures without photoshop?

Tags: software-recommendation

Next Week I will travel and want to make some pictures without tourists.

With photoshop you can easily remove all people from pictures.

Not only one or two, but all people.

But photoshop is not free software and pretty expensive. I can use only free

trial version but not sure if I can use this technique in trial version.

That's why I am looking for another software which can remove ALL PEOPLE from

pictures.

I know I can remove a person or an object with lasso or brush but it will take

very very long time to remove ALL PEOPLE..

Comment: Do you shoot with a tripod

Comment: @joojaa I don't have any tripod and don't want use money for this just for 4 days journey. I am a poor guy who will start study in august..

Comment: Photoshop does not exactly remove people from photos automatically either.

Comment: @joojaa I found it is possible in photoshop. https://lifehacker.com/remove-people-from-your-photos-with-this-photoshop-scri-1245505649. This article introduces how to do that with photoshop. Need some free software which can do similar thing.. as I said photoshop is pretty expensive..

Comment: That's why i asked if you have a tripod. You can use similar methods on any system that can take the mean of images. But this means your image needs to be taken on a tripod OR you need to have a clean track and inhumanly steady hand or a really far away target

Comment: @joojaa I have found shomething which is called "Imagemagick". Have you tried it? Can it do such thing something like remove all moving people from for example Eiffel tower picture?

Comment: Yes if you can make a perfect stack. Since you do not have a tripod i doubt it.

Comment: You got this all from the wrong angle; regardless of the software you choose to remove the people you will need multiple photos from the exact same location. For that you need a tripod or a stable surface to put your camera so it doesn't move in between shots. If you don't shoot right, it won't be easy to fix later

Comment: @joojaa thank you for your kindness. Because I don't have any tripod, I will not try in crowd so no one could push me and make stabil as possible as I can

Comment: @Luciano I understand what you mean. Just wondered if there is any software which can do similar function. As I see now a tripod is required for this technique, I will just try to do that without that equipment as possible as I can. I just don't want to waste my money for that just for 4 days of journey.

Comment: Note that a "tripod' isn't absolutely required. You *could* set the camera on *any* stable, unmoving surface to keep it still. Park you car... put the camera on the hood or roof it ... etc. Tripods make aligning the photo much easier, but the "stability' factor can be done with any surface.

Comment: Not sure this will be relevant to the OP, however for users shooting with an iPhone, there's an app for this purpose: https://fstoppers.com/originals/bye-bye-camera-ios-app-says-bye-bye-people-386685

Comment: Or he can release a deadly virus and wait 28 days...

Answer (score 7):

Here's a tip from long experience with Photoshop removing people. Wake up early. I mean really early, grab a banana and skip breakfast. Be the first guy taking that photo. No software needed and this will also save you breakfast money.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, Stacks with Mean are your method - and to avoid the need for tripod-steady shots, you end up having to spend a little money - [**Affinity Photo**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/photo/), though not freeware like GIMP, is in fact very affordable at $49.99 for a perpetual license (cheaper than a tripod anyway) and the Stack setup there involves *very* effective position and angle compensation enough to make *handheld stacks* work just fine for me.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is free software that can do it. It's possible with GIMP and the plugin called G'MIC which has a Median layer blending function.  But you need photos which are aligned - so a tripod is still a must. G'MIC also has an align layers function, but the images still need to be pretty close. If you have no tripod - taking photos using a wall or other prop to steady the camera is also a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I do not want to be rude... There are some really cheap tripods that cost less than $20 Usd or smaller ones that cost less than $8. They are not the most magnificent but do the job.

You can carry a bag of rice and use it to support your camera, but you need some place to support it like a fence or a tree.

The point is, you want to take photos as if you are the producer of a BBC documentary where there are no people on Versailles Palace for the day without investing a cent.

**You need to understand the technique**. You take one photo, but there is a guy standing. Then you take another photo hoping there is no lady now in his place. This needs the exact point of view... so you need a tripod where you can stand repeating some systematic way your shoots.

The systematic technique to merge the photos is called stacking, and that is a secondary step.

Comment: This. A surprising amount of people still believe that all the incredible photos they see are just made with software, disregarding the amount of work to shoot with the right conditions / equipment.

Comment: Most likely would want ND filters as well